# Thymeleaf template engine: syntax for checking variable equals to one in a list of string literals

Tags: thymeleaf

I can compare that value equals a string literal with `th:if="${var} == 'FOO'"`.

To check for several possible values: `th:if="${var == 'FOO' or var == 'BAR'}"`. I wonder if there is some concise syntax for multi value check instead of `or`ing? Like:

```
var in ('FOO', 'BAR', 'BAZ')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems there is a syntax for list literals: `{1, 2, 3}` or `{"a", "b", "c"}`.

Combining with special `#lists.contains()` operator:

```
th:if="${#lists.contains({'FOO','BAR'}, var)}"
```